# JMeter and Python bottle - not closing sockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, jmeter, bottle, cherrypy

We've got an API, written in Python and using Bottle and Cherrypy, which we need to stress test.  We've created a JMeter script to do this, but after a couple of minutes of execution, the calls begin to fail with the following exception:-

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
```

I can't seem to work out how to tell JMeter not to hang onto the sockets, or how to tell Bottle to drop them.  We've tried it with options such as JMeter's KeepAlive on and off but without success.

We've pulled almost everything out of the API and this script still has the problem (without any of our functional baggage).

```
"""
This script provides a dummy API, which responds to every GET as if it found something.
"""

import bottle
import os
import sys
import datetime
import routes

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOST = 'localhost'
    PORT = 5555

    @bottle.route('/thing/:id', builtin_function_or_method='GET')
    def get_thing(id):
        response_json = {
            'data': {
                'type': 'thing',
                'id': id,
                'meta': {
                    'date_retrieved': datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
                }
            }
        }
        bottle.response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public,max-age=0'
        return response_json

    bottle.run(server='cherrypy', host=HOST, port=PORT)
```

This is Python 3.6.5, Cherrypy 8.9.1 and JMeter 3.3 running on Windows.

Comment: A combination of a very high timeout (JMeter HTTP Request Advanced tab) and "KeepAlive" seems to have done the job, although I'm now sceptical about whether the performance test has the same value with connections being reused.  Throughput (on laptop) is 1000s per second.

Comment: Are you in a windows system ? If so this is your solution - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/196271/when-you-try-to-connect-from-tcp-ports-greater-than-5000-you-receive-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come across similar while running JMeter stress tests from a windows machine. This should happen due to port limitations set up by windows as standard. There are 5000 default ports as per their docs. You may try increasing this value using this [guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/196271/when-you-try-to-connect-from-tcp-ports-greater-than-5000-you-receive-t)

Comment: Many thanks.  I've set the MaxUserPorts to 65534 as suggested, and this has definitely improved performance.  I'm still getting a lot of "address in use" errors, though.  I've been setting up the test on my laptop so far (Windows 7).  When we do it for real, it'll be on Windows 2012 R2.

Comment: Sorry, also meant to add that I had changed TcpTimedWaitDelay to 30 as well.  The test runs for longer before the errors start to appear and there are fewer of them overall (but still 9% over a five minute run).

Comment: @JeremyGooch not sure what the issue you face now. Are yo sure that you are closing connections ? I mean is  there chance to have a  hanged connection caused by a test case ?

Comment: I've now had a chance to test this out on the actual server we're going to use (Windows 2012 R2).  I didn't experience any of the problems (we benchmarked the service at 2300tps), so I'm going to assume that it's a feature of Windows 7.  Thanks for your help.